# german tourist or German tourist?

Tags: capitalization

I have learned that 'german' as a noun, written with upper case letter whilst 'german' as an adjective should be with lower case letter.  Please guide me more by posting the rules if necessary.

Comment: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/German#Adjective, http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/german#Adjective. Compare for yourself. Or check any other dictionary of your choice.

Comment: Another rule about german is that you can add an *e* to make it into an [adjective](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/germane#Adjective).

Answer (score 1):

There are some compound nouns, like "french fries", which are common enough that people use lower case for them. However, this doesn't apply to most uses of "German". Maybe you could write "german measles" (although this is usually capitalized). But you certainly shouldn't write *"a german automobile" or *"a german tourist".

Comment: From 'Grammar Girl': ... whether you capitalize names of food or drinks that contain proper nouns is a style choice. The Chicago Manual of Style has the clearest rule: don’t capitalize these terms unless the names literally refer to the city or person. For example, Chicago says don’t capitalize “swiss cheese” unless you’re talking about cheese that comes from Switzerland. Following the Chicago rules, you wouldn’t capitalize the “french” in “french fries” or the “irish” in “irish coffee.”

...

CMS notes, however, that they are in conflict with their own recommended dictionary, Webster’s Third.

Comment: And I'd always capitalise say 'Peking duck', 'Danish pastry', 'Bakewell tart', 'Black Forest gateau' ... no matter where they were being made.